# Different behavior in const auto& for C++ in Mac and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, macos

I am currently facing different behavior problem in Mac and Linux. I have the following code in file `test_max.cpp`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

float func(float a) {
    float b = a;
    return b;
}

int main() {
    float a = 0.6, b = 1;

    const auto& a1 = func(a);
    const auto& b1 = func(b);
    const auto& res1 = std::max(func(a), func(b));
    const auto& res2 = std::max(a1, b1);

    std::cout << "res1: " << res1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "res2: " << res2 << std::endl;
}
```

This is how I compiled the code.

```
g++ -std=c++11  -01 -o test_max test_max.cpp && ./test_max
```

On Mac, it returns me the same value for both `res1` and `res2` as 1. However, on linux, it returns 0 for `res1` always. I don't know why. Could someone help me?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] to reproduce those different behaviors you claim please.

Comment: how do you know what it returns? Are you using a debugger?

Comment: Perhaps both `func1` and `func2` return 0 if `__linux__` is defined?

Comment: @user463035818 Yeah, also I printed out the value

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read about [mcve] and provide one.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I checked the function, and print inside. it won't return 0.

Comment: As long as you refuse to provide a [mcve] you will not be able to get a helpful response

Comment: it is not `std::max` that is broken, but code that you do not show us

Comment: What does `func1` and `func2` return? If they are returning by-value, then `max_val` may be a dangling reference, which is UB. This would explain a difference in behavior

Comment: Sorry guys. I am new to stack overflow. I just updated the question. Hope now it makes sense

Comment: @Verse : Turns out @Bitwize is right. `max_val` is a dangling reference, in which case the output is undefined - which perfectly explains why you're getting different results across compilers.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Hey, thank you so much for your answer, now I know why!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see different behavior under different compilers, you are most likely in the realm of undefined behavior (or possibly merely unspecified behavior). In this case, the undefined behavior comes from accessing a dangling reference (`res1`).

> `const auto& res1 = std::max(func(a), func(b));`

This line initializes `res1` as a reference to whatever `std::max` returns, setting up the possibility of a dangling reference. A priori, it is just a possibility; some similar-looking lines do not create dangling references. The first factor to look at is the outermost function, `std::max`. If that function were to return by value (a.k.a. return a temporary), the lifetime of that temporary would be extended so that `res1` is not dangling. However, that is not the case, as it returns a reference. Not just any reference, but a reference to one of its parameters. Still, this is fine, as long as the returned parameter is not itself a temporary. Alas, `func()` returns by value, not by reference. So we are indeed in a bad case.

1. Parameter to `max` is a temporary.
2. `max` returns a reference to its parameter.

This is the situation described in the third bullet point of [Lifetime of a temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) @ cppreference.com. The result is a dangling reference, and accessing it to print its value invokes undefined behavior.

---

It might be interesting to note that adding another function call can resolve the undefined behavior:

```
const auto& res1 = func(std::max(func(a), func(b)));
```

Of course, if `func` was something other than the identity function, this would change the functionality. But, as far as undefined behavior goes, the value returned by the outermost `func` is a *copy* of the temporary returned by `func(b)`. It is a new temporary being immediately bound to a reference variable, so its lifetime gets extended. All is good.

Then again, the more typical fix for this line would be to remove the ampersand...
Eh, learning exercise.